# Android Using Jar Files

Tags: java, android, eclipse, dependencies, jreddit

So I'm trying to use the jReddit wrapper class because I am developing a reddit app on the android. Here is what I did:

1. I first went to [jreddit](https://github.com/jReddit/jReddit) and downloaded as a zip
2. Then I went to eclipse, made a project and copied the files from the extracted folder into the new project. Here's a picture of what it looks like:
   [image]
3. Then I used the `build.xml` from [here](https://github.com/hormigas/jReddit/blob/master/build.xml) and "Ran as Ant" to create a jar file in the `dist` folder as you can see above
4. I made my android project and copied the jar file into the `lib` folder and built the path. The project looks like this:
   [image]
5. Finally, here is my [MainActivity.java](http://pastebin.com/NSRK4uzX). Sorry, I couldn't format the code properly on here

There are no errors, so I can run it on the android. However, when I click the login button to activate the function call `onClickBtn`, before it can even get into the function it throws an error saying: `Could not find class 'im.goel.jreddit.user.User', referenced from method com.example.reddit.MainActivity.onClickBtn`

Did I not import this jar in correctly or am i just not using it properly? Why is it compiling fine like it can see the user class but when run on the android it doesn't know what it is?

Comment: Hi, 

All the things is okey. you just need to create a instance os User class. then you can call any method of that class.

e.g. `User redditUser;` before onCreate();

Then you can call `redditUser = new User(usern, passw);` 

    under onClickBtn();

Try this way, may it works.

Comment: @VikashKumar no it still has the same error before entering the function. I put a breakpoint on the first line; at the `String usern = username.getText().toString();` and the error is being thrown before hitting the breakpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the contents to the same folder as your other classes. Usually *src*.

Or

Go to project properties (*Alt + Enter*) and select *Java Build Path* (Left panel). Then select *Libraries* (Top middle). Click the *Add External JARs* button and select your jar.